# Момент, когда новая сессия ещё не началась, а входные данные система уже проверила

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

Здравствуйте! Дано: проект на Laravel 5.4. Нужно, когда пользователь авторизуется, проверить, набрал ли он товары в корзину ранее (до авторизации, то есть). Товары в корзине сразу же после выбора пользователем добавляются в БД. Если пользователь на момент выбора был не авторизован, то в записях указывается id сессии. По этому id записи можно и "вытащить".

Когда пользователь авторизуется, естественно, начинается новая сессия. Теперь вопрос. Где можно "отловить" момент, когда новая сессия ещё не началась, а входные данные система уже проверила? Хотя бы в какую сторону смотреть? Или такого момента в Laravel попросту нет?

Comment: По заголовкам request и response можно увидеть когда данные отправились на проверку и когда пришел ответ проверки. И вот этот момент между запросом и ответом сервером и будет временем когда пользователь еще не имеет новой сессии, но на сервере он уже залогинен. По идеи как то так... Но не уверен на все 100%

Comment: А что мешает перед авторизацией положить в куку старую сессию ? и после авторизации оттуда взять и убить  ?